# Transform Graphs For Free Falling

Tags: modeling, animation

I created big cube on the plane with using a lot of small cube. I used  array option for this. And I want to raise plane from one side and observe falling small cubes. And I want to see their transform graphs. This is my thesis. Can you help me please?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by transform graphs? Do you mean what is in the graph editor?

Comment: If you've used array to create cubes and want these cubes to be separate objects, you need to apply the Array, then go in Edit mode, select all and press P > By Loose Parts

Comment: and once they are loose you need to set the origin. Select all the separated Cubes and press Space and type origin, click Set Origin and select Origin to Geometry. Now you can use the Physics tab to make them Active and set the "floor" to Passive for them to fall on to.

Comment: Thank you for all you for interest. I made all this already. I just want to see the transform graph. For example I want to select one small cube and after animate I want to observe transform this cube in the graph. I mean I want to see path graph for cube which I selected.